# expandable list view with nested json parsing

Tags: android, json

I have a working on a project in which we have to parse a nested json array and display it in a expandable listview with 2 level,now i have get only first item of 
group and their chield item.I am new to android development please help me to achieve this . My code is given below..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    JSONObject obj,subObj;
    JSONArray subcatarray,jarray;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String cat_id="2";
    int j;
    JsonParser  jsonParser=new JsonParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://sion.in/kandly/services/serviceList.php?service=subcategory";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();



        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {


        new Subcatagory().execute();
    }
    private class Subcatagory extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_id", cat_id));
                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script 
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                System.out.println("devjsondata"+json);

                jarray=json.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0;i<=jarray.length();i++){
                    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                    obj=jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    listDataHeader.add(obj.getString("cat_name"));

                    subcatarray=obj.getJSONArray("product_details");

                    List<String> pSubItemArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(j=0;j<=subcatarray.length();j++){

                        subObj=subcatarray.getJSONObject(j);

                        pSubItemArrayList.add(subObj.optString("product_name"));
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), pSubItemArrayList);
                    }

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

and my adapter class is-

```
public static class BasexpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Product>ListTerbaru;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<SubCategory>> ListChildTerbaru;
    ArrayList<String>counterlist;
    //private int[] itemcounter=new int[ListChildTerbaru.size()];
    //final int count[] = {1};
    //String subcount;
    //SubCategory subcat;

    Boolean showText=false;
    public BasexpandableListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Product>ListTerbaru,ArrayList<ArrayList<SubCategory>> listChildXX){
        this.context=context;
        this.ListTerbaru=ListTerbaru;
        this.ListChildTerbaru=listChildXX;
        //      this.count=ListTerbaru.size();
        //      this.count=ListChildTerbaru.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public SubCategory getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final SubCategory childTerbaru = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = null;   
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_second, parent,false);
            //counter=0;
            totalValueOfCounter+=totalValueOfCounter;
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.begdate1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            holder.countertext=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.countettext);
            holder.increament=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.increment);
            holder.decrement=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrement);

            holder.increament.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                        try{
                        counter = Integer.parseInt(holder.countertext.getText().toString().trim());
                        }catch(NumberFormatException e){

                        }
                        counter++; 

                        SubCategory element = (SubCategory)holder.increament.getTag(); 
                        element.setScore(Integer.toString(counter)); 
                        holder.countertext.setText(childTerbaru.getScore().trim());


                        //totalValueOfCounter=childTerbaru.getScore();
                         totaleamount.setText(totalValueOfCounter);
                        try{
                            totaleamount.setText(Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getItemPrice())*Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getScore())));
                            totalValueOfCounter=Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getItemPrice())*Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getScore()));

                        }catch(NumberFormatException e){

                        }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });
            holder.decrement.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try{
                            counter = Integer.parseInt(holder.countertext.getText().toString().trim());
                            }catch(NumberFormatException e){

                            }
                        if(counter>0){
                            counter--;
                        }       

                        SubCategory element = (SubCategory) holder.decrement.getTag(); 
                        element.setScore(Integer.toString(counter)); 
                        holder.countertext.setText(childTerbaru.getScore().trim());
                        //totalValueOfCounter=Integer.toString(counter);
                        //totalValueOfCounter
                        totaleamount.setText(totalValueOfCounter);
                        try{
                            totaleamount.setText(Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getItemPrice())*Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getScore())));
                            totalValueOfCounter=Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getItemPrice())*Double.parseDouble(childTerbaru.getScore()));

                        }catch(NumberFormatException e){

                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            holder.increament.setTag(childTerbaru);  
            holder.decrement.setTag(childTerbaru); 
            holder.countertext.setTag(childTerbaru); 
            holder.begdate1.setTag(childTerbaru); 

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.begdate1.setText(childTerbaru.getpSubCatName());
            //holder.countertext.setText(childTerbaru.getScore()); 
        }
        else{
            view = convertView; 
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).countertext.setTag(childTerbaru); 
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).increament.setTag(childTerbaru); 
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).decrement.setTag(childTerbaru); 
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).begdate1.setTag(childTerbaru); 
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            holder.begdate1.setText(childTerbaru.getpSubCatName());
            holder.countertext.setText(childTerbaru.getScore()); 

            return view;
          }
            holder.begdate1.setText(childTerbaru.getpSubCatName());
            holder.countertext.setText(childTerbaru.getScore()); 
        // holder.countertext.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        //  holder.countertext.setText(ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getScore()); 
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).size();

    }

    @Override
    public Product getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return ListTerbaru.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return ListTerbaru.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Product terbaruModel = (Product) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ViewHolder holder= null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, parent,false);

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.nama=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            // holder.alamat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.nama.setText(terbaruModel.getpName());
        //holder.alamat.setText(terbaruModel.getAlamat());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView begdate1,nama,countertext;
        Button increament,decrement;
    }

}
```

my json response is-

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "status": "true",
        "message": "found",
        "cat_id": "24",
        "cat_name": "MEN",
        "product_details": [
            {
                "message": "found",
                "product_id": "17",
                "product_name": "irt",
                "price": "77.000000"
            },
            {
                "message": "found",
                "product_id": "22",
                "product_name": "sers",
                "price": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "status": "true",
        "message": "fnd",
        "cat_id": "5",
        "cat_name": "WOMEN",
        "product_details": [
            {
                "message": "fod",
                "product_id": "17",
                "product_name": "irt",
                "price": "700"
            },
            {
                "message": "foud",
                "product_id": "7",
                "product_name": "Shrt",
                "price": "00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Lot of thanks for your help.I was really stuck at this for long time.Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition in your two for-loop from `<=` to `<`.

I bet you have **IndexOutOfBoundException** in your log. After looping all the first item's child the system exit the loop because of it.

They should be:

```
for( int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++ )
for( int j=0; j<subcatarray.length() ;j++ )
```

Comment: i have another problem on adapter class when set increament decreament counter in each child item.i am trying to add onclick listener in getchildview method on both buton for increament and decreament.but i get repeat value after few items whem i press increament or decreament.@rami

Comment: Please accept the answer ifit olve your OP problem. And if you have another one you should ask a new question, this is how *Stackoverflow* works. I don't understand what you mean by *"i get repeat value after few items"* ?

Comment: Please tell me how to set counter on child item.and how to get position of each counter text of child item.@Rami

Comment: I suggest you to create a Model object for your child, that contains a *String* (for  the name/child text) and an *int* for the counter. And when you increment/decrement the child you should update his value. So you'll always have the right counter value in the child model, and you'll never lost it.

Comment: I am doing that but when i scroll the list the item refresh and counter set to zero.how to do that counter remains unchanged on scrolling

Comment: You need to update your data set after updating the model.

Comment: hi.. i have update my adapter class.two button are set to onclicklistener for increament and decreament.counter is working fine but problem is that when the counter is increament or decreament the value of counter is update automaticaly on respective child item of each group item.@rami